# How to do Bundling of css & js files in Drupal

Tags: drupal, seo, drupal-6, pagespeed

I am .Net guy.  I have been  assigned a task where I need to bundle the css & js files for the purpose of optimization in Drupal website.

In ASP.Net, we configure all the bundles in bundle.config and upload the dll to production.

Same thing I need to do in Drupal v6.0. Yesterday while googling I found the documentation on Drupal which guides to configure in ***admin/settings/performance*** where I need to enable the Bundling.

But since there in no build thing in Drupal how do I bundle the css & js files on Dev/Production server.

I am using Drupal v6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal

1. Login to your site as admin
2. Under SiteConfiguration, find Perfomance(admin/settings/performance)
3. You will find Bandwidth Optimizations Settings
4. Enable Optimize CSS & JS files.
5. Save Configuration & reload.

In case if doesn't reflect just Clear Site cache. 
Thats it.

Minfication & Bundling both will be achived.